# Tiling shower- filling gaps between tile and drywall

Tags: drywall, shower, tile, grout

Hi all – I would love some creative ideas to fill a couple of small gaps left by a bad tile installation job. Tile goes most of the way up the wall in the shower stall, and then backer board. There are a couple of places where they left a gap between the tile, the backer board, and the drywall of the exterior walls.

Do I just pack these areas with grout? Mud? Tiny drywall patch?  Any great ideas of how to transition them more smoothly? If grout, do I have to worry about the size of the grout based on the size of the area to fill?

Thanks!

[image: 1/4 inch gap between drywall and tile]

[image: big gap between joining surfaces]

[image: overall view]

Comment: Can you post another pic showing the general area, like a "big picture" view? What is the plan for finishing those areas with exposed backer-board? Why is that 1" strip of drywall there, with no corner-bead?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it — picture posted in OP. For the rest of the exposed backer board, I’m planning on just mudding over and painting. I’ll still have to put in the corner bead, but didn’t want to do that until I addressed the gaps. This was a very incomplete job when we had to fire the contractors, so I’m trying to clean it up best I can.  Thanks!

Comment: Top picture- drywall mud. Bottom picture- grout up to the height of the metal  trim piece, drywall mud above that.